# Why does node.js need python

Tags: python, node.js

I am starting up with node
This is from node.js README.md

Prerequisites (Unix only):

```
* GCC 4.2 or newer
* Python 2.6 or 2.7
* GNU Make 3.81 or newer
* libexecinfo (FreeBSD and OpenBSD only)
```

Curious to know why does node.js need Python ? 
Does it use Python underneath its API

Comment: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation  "python 2.6 or 2.7. The build tools distributed with Node run on python."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Node.js is built with [GYP](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/) — cross-platform built tool written in Python. Also some other build steps are implemented in Python. So Python is required for building node from source.

But you also need Python for building native addons.

Comment: has there ever been a conversation on converting the node.js depending on python through gyp to something native (like node,js itself)?

Comment: @BrandonRos, here is one from 2015-2017, though I wish I knew of a more recent one: https://github.com/nodejs/NG/issues/24

Comment: @BrandonRos here are a couple more:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1791
https://github.com/nodejs/TSC/issues/648

Answer (score 3):

Yes, node uses some python scripts under the hood, though Node is largely written in C++.

See some of Node's python code here:

https://github.com/joyent/node/tree/master/tools

E.g., js2c.py converts Javascript into C-style char arrays:

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/tools/js2c.py

In general, if a package tells you that it requires Python, then it is almost certainly using Python ;)

Comment: It sure is using Python :) . But is Python used just during installation or during the run time of node scripts as well ? If the latter will it affect the performance in those cases

Comment: Python is not used at runtime.