# Error installing webdriverIO using "npm install wdio"

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, npm-install, webdriver-io

I'm seeing this error after i run the following commands:
npm install webdriverio

npm install mocha

npm install selenium-standalone

.\node_modules.bin\selenium-standalone install

error seen after running this:

npm install wdio

any advise on how to fix this guys, it is greatly appreciated.. thanks

```
D:\MyTest02>npm install wdio
npm WARN deprecated webdriverio@4.14.4: outdated version, please use @next
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

> fibers@4.0.2 install D:\MyTest02\node_modules\fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js


D:\MyTest02\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\seanr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node "C:\Users\seanr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\seanr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\seanr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\seanr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\seanr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:283:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:295:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:211:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:196:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\seanr\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\MyTest02\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for wdio@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.12.0","npm":"6.14.2"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: wdio@4.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for fibers@4.0.2: wanted: {"node":">=10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.12.0","npm":"6.14.2"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: fibers@4.0.2
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MyTest02\package.json'
npm WARN MyTest02 No description
npm WARN MyTest02 No repository field.
npm WARN MyTest02 No README data
npm WARN MyTest02 No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@4.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@4.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\seanr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-04T13_56_34_890Z-debug.log
```

any advise on this is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something related to the latest version of NodeJS which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709739/why-does-node-js-need-python). I would advise you below two options to get rid of this. Choose the best that suits you.

- Please setup python in your machine
- Downgrade your Nodejs to version 10.X and try it. I am using 10.18.0 and it works perfectly fine. You can download it from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

Cheers!

Comment: installing https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ and adding its path environment variables fixed it. thanks